# What captures the <Shift>+<Ins> key combination?

Tags: cut-copy-paste, terminal

When I press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>Ins</kbd> in vim to paste text, who captures this key combination? Is it the terminal or `Vim`? How about in `gVim`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read from [`:h <S-Insert>`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/os_dos.html#<S-Insert>) that the key combination <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>insert</kbd> is a Vim mapping. That explain why it allows to past text in terminal Vim but also in gVim.

Now about the terminal, it really depends on your system: some terminal are configured to handle this mapping and some other are not.

For example, you can see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/a/402491/408927) where a tool is needed to make gnome-terminal handle the mapping.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know the right way to look for the manual was to use `<S-Insert>`. I mistaked to use `:h <Shift-Ins>`.

Comment: Yes it's not always obvious, when in doubt you can just type `<S` and then use autocomplete